# Duplicate a list Item from the original item

Tags: custom-list, duplicate

I have SPD 2010, but do not have access to additional coding options.  Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Scenario: Users enter items in a list through an OOTB SP "Add New Item" form.  For simplicity, here is the scenario.

Column 1 is Name (Choice, DROP DOWN menu, options are: John, Mary, Bob, only one choice is allowed)

Column 2 is Pets (Choice, CHECKBOX, options are:  Dog, Cat, Fish, MULTIPLE choices can be selected)

Example entries:

1. Bob chooses Dog, Cat
2. Mary chooses Dog, Cat and Fish
3. John chooses Fish

The result of the entries are:

Name | Pets

Bob | Dog, Cat

Mary | Dog, Cat, Fish

John | Fish

I would like a Workflow to run (upon new entry) to insert items into new list (OR update the CURRENT list) WITH THE RESULT being:

Two (2) indentical items for Bob, except one item has only Dog and one has only Cat (in Pets field)

Three (3) indentical item for Mary, except one item has only Dog and one has only Cat and one has only Fish (in Pets field)

One (1) item for John, item has Fish (in Pets field) - NOTE: no change from INITIAL ENTRY because the intial entry only had 1 pet from the start.

Can someone please help with this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can create a similar list for updating the data and follow the following steps:

1. After the item is created, Read the Pets field and do some string manipulations to get how many new items do you require.
2. Now you need to create a loop to add items in your new list. So, out of the box there is no looping activity available in SPD. So you can look at following options to acheive this:

http://brianscodingexamples.wordpress.com/2013/05/09/create-while-loop-within-workflow-in-sharepoint-designer-2010/

https://social.technet.microsoft.com/wiki/contents/articles/14572.for-each-behavior-custom-action-in-sharepoint-designer-2010.aspx

http://www.fabiangwilliams.com/2012/04/02/solving-recursive-loops-in-sharepoint-designer-using-sandboxed-solutions/

3 In you loop statement you can create new items in your list.

Comment: Aanchal - THANK YOU so much for taking the time to reply.  I greatly appreciate your feedback and I will look into the direction you provided.  Sincerely, Scott